# Inverse of a sixth order polynomial function

Tags: functions, polynomials, inverse-function, symmetric-polynomials

I have the [following polynomial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%283.4675*10%5E-4%29*x%5E2%20-%283.5116*10%5E-8%29*x%5E4%2B%288.361*10%5E-13%29*x%5E6) which has the following form:

$F_X \left ({x} \right)= Ax^2-Bx^4 + Cx^6$

Where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are real positive and non-zero. The roots are $\pm 161.634$, $\pm 125.993$ and $0$ . **I am now in need of finding (or approximate) its inverse.**

I have found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701061/is-there-a-way-of-approximating-a-polynomials-inverse) similar post from a couple of years ago where the Lagrange inversion method is recommended, but I do not think it can be applied to my situation. I found [this](http://www.scielo.org.mx/pdf/rmfe/v52n2/v52n2a9.pdf) nice paper where a method was outlined based on finding some coefficients of a pre-defined polynomial, but it yields poor results when far from zero.

This question is part of a [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060842/calculating-the-inverse-of-a-cdf-which-is-a-polynomial?noredirect=1#comment8389201_4060842) that I am solving. Any help/guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can invert this polynomial locally, but not globally. So obviously, any approximation is going to get worse the farther you are from the center of inversion.

Comment: @DonThousand that would be great. Could it be done in a range of lets say $0 < x < 80$? Is there only one range where it could be done or can it be done in different regions? Thanks for your response btw

Comment: There are certain points where it can't be done at all, but at all but finitely many points, there exists some neighborhood in which one can invert. $(0,80)$ doesn't work

Comment: You can invert the function on intervals where it doesn't turn around. That is, it is either increasing or decreasing over the entire interval. From the graph, it looks like $(0,80)$ might work. It depends on exactly where that maximum near $80$ is. It will be the upper limit to the interval.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $F_X(x) = P(g(x))$, where $P(x) = Cx^3 - Bx^2 + Ax$ and $g(x) = x^2$. Over domains where they are invertible, $$F_X^{-1}(y) = g^{-1}(P^{-1}(y))$$

Since you are interested in $x > 0$, $g$ is invertible with $g^{-1}(y) = \sqrt y$. And $P$ is a cubic, for which we have [well-known means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula) [of inverting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions). For calculations, I recommend the trigonometric method (applied to the equation $P(t) - y = 0$ to solve for $t$). Once you find this $t$, set $x = \sqrt t$ to find $x = F_X^{-1}(y)$.